# BigQuery - Access denied and problem with credentials

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I am trying to interface my jupyter notebook with my account on Google Cloud. I have a student grant coupon and everything is set correctly on my profile.

This is my IAM section from my dashboard:
[IAM section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8uXi3.png)

For both users, roles are owner of the project and BigQuery Admin.

When I try to interface it with jupyter, error 403 appears to me. More precisely: [Error 403](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HHCyY.png)

These are my settings and the imported libraries: [Libraries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EtQ3F.png)

Can you help me figuring out where I made mistake?

Thanks in advance :)